# table strings in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R

```
[[1]]
 [1] "Cozinha"           "Piso porcelanato"  

[[2]]
 [1] "Cozinha"           "Piso porcelanato"  "Churrasqueira"     "Elevador"          "Playground"
```

I want something like:

term | count

cozinha | 2

Piso porcelanato  | 2

Churrasqueira  | 1

Elevador | 1

Playground |1

Answer (score 3):

`as.data.frame(table(unlist(your_list)))`